# Distribution of discrete Geometric average and Stock Price

Tags: option-pricing, geometric-brownian, normal-distribution, risk-neutral

If we have $$S_t = S_0 e^{(r-\frac{1}{2} \sigma ^2) +\sigma W_t}$$ and a discrete geometric average of stock prices $$G_n = (\prod_{i=1}^{n} S_{t_i})^{\frac{1}{n}} $$ where the monitoring points are spaced equally as $t_i=i \frac{T}{N}$, where $0 \leq i \leq N$, i.e. $0 \leq t_i \leq T$

How can I find the distribution of $ln(\frac{G_n}{S_T})$, i.e. finding expected value and variance? I have tried rewriting $G_n$ using natural logs so that: $$ln(G_n) = \frac{1}{n} \left ( ln(S_{t_1})+ln(S_{t_2})+ln(S_{t_3})+...+ln(S_{t_N}) \right )$$ but I am unsure of how to combine it with $S_T$.

Note that since I am new to much of this notation there might be inconsistencies so please fix them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$\begin{align}
\ln \left(\frac{G_T}{S_T}  \right)&=  \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\ln(S_{t_i})-\ln(S_T)\\
&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n  \left(\ln(S_{t_i})-\ln(S_T)\right)\\
&=-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n  \left((r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)(T-t_i)+\sigma(W_T-W_{t_i})\right)\\
&=(r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)\left(-T+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n  t_i\right)+\sigma \left( -W_T+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n  W_{t_i}\right)\\
&=\underbrace{(r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)\left(-T+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n  t_i\right)}_{=:\color{red}{\mu}}+\sigma \underbrace{\left( -W_T+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n  W_{t_i}\right)}_{=:\mathcal{L}}\\
\end{align}$$

The term $\mathcal{L}$ follows the normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(0,\color{red}{\Sigma})$ as it is the sum of the $(W_{t_i})_{i=1,...,n}$. To determine $\Sigma$, it suffices to compute
$$\begin{align}
\Sigma &=\mathbb{E}\left(\left( -W_T+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n  W_{t_i}\right)^2\right)\\
 &=\mathbb{E}\left(W_T^2\right) -2\frac{1}{n}\mathbb{E}\left(W_T \sum_{i=1}^n  W_{t_i}\right)+\frac{1}{n^2}\mathbb{E}\left(\left(\sum_{i=1}^n  W_{t_i}\right)^2\right)  \tag{1}
\end{align}$$
I let you compute  $\Sigma$ by using the property $\mathbb{E}(W_xW_y) = \min\{x,y \}$ (it is not difficult)

Finally,
$$\ln \left(\frac{G_T}{S_T}  \right) \sim \mathcal{N}(\color{red}{\mu}, \color{red}{\Sigma})$$

Comment: This is crazy good thanks!